# change a global variable value in a function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a global variable and I want to change its value in a jQuery function like this:

```
var namep ='';

$("#page2").bind('pageshow', function (event , data) {
   var perso = $(this).data("url").split("?")[1];;
   perso_name = perso.replace("perso=","");
   namep=perso_name;
   $("#header h2").text(perso_name); 
});

alert(namep);
```

In my alert I have nothing so I think `namep` doesn't change. How can I change its value?

Comment: put the alert inside the function. You are manipulating the value in the function. So variable wont change unless the event is fired

Comment: Is the person's name showing up in the `#header`?

Comment: yes it's him @DevlshOne

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does get changed; it's just that you're checking it too soon -- before it is changed. You should put the alert in the `handler`, where the value is changed:

```
var namep ='';

$("#page2").bind('pageshow', function (event , data) {
    var perso = $(this).data("url").split("?")[1];;
    perso_name = perso.replace("perso=","");
    namep=perso_name;
    alert(namep);
    $("#header h2").text(perso_name); 
});
```

Comment: yeah it's change inside the function I want to change his value for all of the script.
Thx.

Comment: And you are doing it already. Use your event, then open the console and write `alert(namep)`.

Comment: Correct. As @kmsdev has put it you are changing the value. **Once it is changed**, that value is available to your whole page. You're just having a little misunderstanding about the timing. **Timing is key**.